# Encryption For Azure Blob

Tags: java, azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage

I want to store the data in an azure blob in an encrypted format.I am using [This](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-client-side-encryption-java/) as a reference.

```
RsaKey key = new RsaKey("private:key1" /* key identifier */);
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(null, null);
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
options.setEncryptionPolicy(policy);
boolean tableExistsOrNOt = true;
if (blobContainer == null) {
    tableExistsOrNOt = blobContainer.createIfNotExists();
}
if (tableExistsOrNOt) {
    CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.getBlockBlobReference(xml.get(ecnNumberKey).toString());
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        xml.get(xmlKey).toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        //  blob.upload(inputStream, inputStream.available());
        //  blob.upload(inputStream, inputStream.available(), null, options, null);
        blob.upload(inputStream, inputStream.available(),null, options, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception while inserting xml to blob in PLMSubscriberMSDaoImpl.insertPayloadXMLToBlob", e);
        LOG.info("#####Ending PLMSubscriberMSDaoImpl.insertPayloadXMLToBlob#####");
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this I am getting followig exception at `blob.upload(inputStream, inputStream.available(),null, options, null);` 
The Stack trace is as follows:

```
`com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: A Client side exception occurred, please check the inner exception for details
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateClientException(StorageException.java:42) ~[azure-storage-4.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobEncryptionPolicy.createAndSetEncryptionContext(BlobEncryptionPolicy.java:305) ~[azure-storage-4.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.upload(CloudBlockBlob.java:669) ~[azure-storage-4.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.jci.subscriber.dao.PLMSubscriberMSDaoImpl.insertPayloadXMLToBlob(PLMSubscriberMSDaoImpl.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.jci.subscriber.service.PLMSubscriberMSServiceImpl.azureMessageSubscriber(PLMSubscriberMSServiceImpl.java:174) [classes/:na]
    at com.jci.subscriber.PLMSubscriberMSApplication.azureSBXMLPost(PLMSubscriberMSApplication.java:78) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]`
```

Comment: As per the article you referenced, `RsaKey` is in _azure-keyvault-extensions_

Comment: @MartinParkin It is giving an exception at `blob.upload(inputStream, inputStream.available(),null, options, null);`

Comment: Just dropped by to mention Encryption At Rest is now offered as a feature (Preview): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-service-encryption/

Answer (score 0):

@eddie, It seems to be caused by using `inputStream.available()` as the parameter of the size of the upload content, please try to use the code below to fix the issue.

```
try {
    byte[] buf = xml.get(xmlKey).toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int size = buf.length;
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    //  blob.upload(inputStream, inputStream.available());
    //  blob.upload(inputStream, inputStream.available(), null, options, null);
    blob.upload(inputStream, size,null, options, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Exception while inserting xml to blob in PLMSubscriberMSDaoImpl.insertPayloadXMLToBlob", e);
    LOG.info("#####Ending PLMSubscriberMSDaoImpl.insertPayloadXMLToBlob#####");
    return false;
}
```

As reference, there is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage-samples/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/encryption/keyvault/gettingstarted/KeyVaultGettingStarted.java) of Client-Side Encryption with Java for Microsoft Azure Storage which you can refer to.
Hope it helps.